# How can I create a rule that takes one argument by referring to a rule that takes two arguments? (Beginner)

Tags: prolog

I want to create the following rule:

```
rule2(X) :-
  is "true" if rule1(X,Y) is false.
```

---

So rule2 will output a "true" for `X`, if rule1 outputs a "false" for `X` and *any* value `Y`

---

I hope this makes sense. I'm a beginner at `prolog`. It's been fun but I've been stuck on this issue for hours! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use a logical not, `\+/1` in favour of a `!, fail` approach:

```
rule2(X):- \+ (rule1(X,_)).
```